# Issue when binding text between UITextField with UIViewRepresentable and SwifUI

Tags: swiftui, uikit, uitextfield, uiviewrepresentable

I'm trying to make an 'emoji picker' in SwiftUI which brings ups the emoji keyboard, allows the user to select an emoji, and then dismisses the keyboard. I'm using a UITextField wrapped in a UIViewRepresntable with a String Binding, however the string's value never gets updated for some reason.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
/// Allows a user to pick an emoji character using the Emoji keyboard.
/// - Note: This does not prevent the user from manually switching to other keyboards and inputting a non-Emoji character
struct EmojiPicker: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var emoji: String
    
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<EmojiPicker>) -> EmojiUITextField {
        let textField = EmojiUITextField(frame: .zero)
        textField.text = emoji
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        textField.autocorrectionType = .no
        textField.returnKeyType = .done
        textField.textAlignment = .center
        textField.tintColor = .clear
        
        return textField
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: EmojiUITextField, context: Context) {
        self.emoji = uiView.text!
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> EmojiTextFieldCoordinator {
        return EmojiTextFieldCoordinator(self)
    }
}

internal class EmojiTextFieldCoordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
    var emojiTextField: EmojiPicker
    
    init(_ textField: EmojiPicker) {
        self.emojiTextField = textField
    }
    
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        self.emojiTextField.emoji = textField.text!
    }
    
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        textField.text = string
        
        if let text = textField.text, text.count == 1 {
            self.emojiTextField.emoji = textField.text!
            UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
        }
        
        return true
    }
}

internal class EmojiUITextField: UITextField {
    override var textInputContextIdentifier: String? {
        return ""
    }

    override var textInputMode: UITextInputMode? {
        return UITextInputMode.activeInputModes.first {
            $0.primaryLanguage == "emoji"
        }
    }
    
    override func selectionRects(for range: UITextRange) -> [UITextSelectionRect] {
        return []
    }
}
```

All the resources I've found thus far haven't worked, including [this](https://gist.github.com/unnamedd/9346e1b0205ed6e2d09bf4709229a029), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59990634/swiftui-custom-textfield-with-uiviewrepresentable-issue-with-observableobject-an), and [this](https://www.appcoda.com/swiftui-textview-uiviewrepresentable/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is fix, the only modified part, (tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14)

```
func updateUIView(_ uiView: EmojiUITextField, context: Context) {
    if self.emoji != uiView.text! {     // << update only on change, otherwise
        self.emoji = uiView.text!       // it result in cycle and dropped
    }
}
```

Here is a view used for testing

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text = "<none>"
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Get: \(text)")
            EmojiPicker(emoji: $text)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, it's still not working for me (I'm using iOS 14 as well)

Comment: Turns out it actually because in my SwiftUI preview struct, I was using the `@State` there directly instead of using another struct

Comment: The assignment in `updateUIView` feels backwards. Shouldn't updateUIView take outside information (the binding to `self.emoji`), and update its appearance to match? I would think this should be `uiView.text = self.emoji`. (You would then need to use `addTarget` to update `self.emoji` as typing occurs.) As written, if an emoji is assigned to the `emoji` binding, this view won't update, right?

Comment: Here's an example that I've been working on based on your code (but with updateUIView working the other direction). https://gist.github.com/rnapier/bd3a9a5949fe809f7cd9568d85b3e281