# SwiftUI custom textfield not getting updated value

Tags: swift, swiftui

I would like to create a custom text field with some input buttons, on click of those buttons text field should update the value accordingly.

I have multiple options to set value in `InputView`, so that if I edited `InputView` and if I click on any button, the button should update the value.

here is my code

```swift
@main
struct AmountApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            InputView()
        }
    }
}
struct InputView: View {
    @State var value: Double = 0.00
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Amount")
            TextInput(value: $value).padding(.horizontal)
            HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 16) {
                Button { value = 20 } label: { Text("20") }
                Button { value = 30 } label: { Text("30") }
                Button { value = 40 } label: { Text("40") }
            }
            
            Button { print(value) } label: {
                Text("Print")
                    .padding(8)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
            }
        }
    }
}


struct TextInput: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var value: Double
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator { Coordinator(self) }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) { }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) ->  UITextField {
        let textfield = UITextField()
        textfield.placeholder = "Enter amount"
        textfield.text = "\(value)"
        textfield.keyboardType = .decimalPad
        textfield.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)
        textfield.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
        textfield.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
        return textfield
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        var parent: TextInput
        init(_ textField: TextInput) { self.parent = textField }
    }
}
```

Help would be greatly appreciated, ~Good day.!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binding value will not update if you don't implement the`UITextFieldDelegate` method(s) to receive user input ([SwiftUI Custom TextField with UIViewRepresentable Issue with ObservableObject and pushed View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59990634/swiftui-custom-textfield-with-uiviewrepresentable-issue-with-observableobject-an))

When you change the value from the SwiftUI side, your UIViewRepresentable needs to handle the change in updateUIView (pass the new value to UITextField)

Also remember to set `textfield.delegate = context.coordinator` so that you receive events.

```
struct TextInput: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var value: Double
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator { Coordinator(self) }
    
    // for handling swiftui-side modification to the binding (your buttons)
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) { 
        uiView.text = value
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) ->  UITextField {
        let textfield = UITextField()
        textfield.placeholder = "Enter amount"
        textfield.text = "\(value)"
        textfield.keyboardType = .decimalPad
        textfield.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)
        textfield.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
        textfield.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
        textfield.delegate = context.coordinator // set the delegate
        return textfield
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        var parent: TextInput
        init(_ textField: TextInput) { self.parent = textField }
        func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
            if let text = textField.text {
                parent.value = Double(text) ?? 0
            } else {
                parent.value = 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```